get duration of raw audio file with javascript
I have a raw audio file like this:
const rawAudio = data:audio/webm;codecs=opus;base64,GkXfo59ChoEBQveBAULygQRC84EIQoKEd2VibUKHgQRChYECGFOAZwH/////////FUmpZpkq17GDD0JATYCGQ2hyb21lV0GGQ2hyb21lFlSua7+uvdeBAXPFh+Wa3g0oH66DgQKGhkFfT1BVU2Oik09wdXNIZWFkAQEAAIC7AAA

And I want to get the duration of this audio file.
Here is what I tried:
const onDrop = (file) => {
  const audio = document.createElement("audio")
  audio.setAttribute("src", URL.createObjectURL(file))
  audio.setAttribute("crossorigin", "anonymous")

  console.log(audio) // 

  audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", () => {
    console.log("loadedmetadata")
    const duration = audio.duration
    console.log(duration)
  })
}

var binaryData = []
binaryData.push(Card.audios.explain[0])

onDrop(new Blob(binaryData))

But loadedmetadata never fires !!
How would you do that?

It looks like the rawAudio is not a supported audio type or is incorrect. Try copying its contents and enter it on the address bar in your browser (and press enter). You'll notice that there'll be no audio to play at all.

Looks like your rawAudio is not supported in your browser.
I made this snippet to show this problem:


function newAudioElement ( myURL )
{
  const myAudioElement = document.createElement('audio');
  {
    myAudioElement.setAttribute('src', myURL);
    myAudioElement.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
  }
  
  // You can add as many event handlers as needed.
  {
    myAudioElement.addEventListener
    (
      'error', myEvent =>
      {
        console.log('Error:', { URL: myURL, ERROR: myEvent.target.error.message });
      }
    );
    
    myAudioElement.addEventListener
    (
      'durationchange', myEvent =>
      {
        console.log('Audio:', { URL: myURL, DURATION: myEvent.target.duration });
      }
    );
  }
  
  return myAudioElement;
}

// Your given audio.
const givenAudio = "data:audio/webm;codecs=opus;base64,GkXfo59ChoEBQveBAULygQRC84EIQoKEd2VibUKHgQRChYECGFOAZwH/////////FUmpZpkq17GDD0JATYCGQ2hyb21lV0GGQ2hyb21lFlSua7+uvdeBAXPFh+Wa3g0oH66DgQKGhkFfT1BVU2Oik09wdXNIZWFkAQEAAIC7AAA";

// A valid audio.
const someValidAudio = "https://cdn.freesound.org/previews/349/349483_827719-lq.ogg";

// TESTS

const newAudio1 = newAudioElement(givenAudio);
const newAudio2 = newAudioElement(someValidAudio);

console.log('Audios:', { newAudio1, newAudio2 });
console.log('Wait for your browser to fetch the audios...');
.as-console-wrapper
{
  min-height: 100%;
}



